# How can I resolve an 'Application Passwords' error when trying to edit a user in Bitnami Wordpress on Azure?

Tags: python, wordpress-rest-api

I installed Bitnami Wordpress virtual machine on Azure. When I edit user, got messages as below:

> Application Passwords
> Application passwords allow authentication via non-interactive systems, such as XML-RPC or the REST API, without providing your actual password. Application passwords can be easily revoked. They cannot be used for traditional logins to your website.
>
> The application password feature requires HTTPS, which is not enabled on this site.

Seems like  application password is not working for my site.
I'm trying to run python to post text and pictures to my web on Bitnami Wordpress Azure.

How can I get API key for Python?
Or which plugin could solve this?

I'm trying to find suitable plugin.

Below is my code:

```
import requests
import json
import base64

url = "http://my-site/wp-json/wp/v2"

user = "user"
password = "**********"

credentials = user + ':' + password
token = base64.b64encode(credentials.encode())
header = {'Authorization': 'Basic ' + token.decode('utf-8')}

post = {
 'date'   : '2023-05-24T10:00:00',
 'title'    : 'Hello World',
 'status'   : 'publish', 
 'content'  : 'This is my first post created using rest API'
}
responce = requests.post(url+'/posts' , headers=header, json=post)

print(responce)
```